# How to access data in AppDelegate from ObservableObject class in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, appdelegate

With the new SwiftUI Lifecycle there normally is no `AppDelegate` anymore. However, in order to implement Firebase Messaging, it is recommended on the Firebase docs to implement an `AppDelegate` and attach it using:

```swift
@main
struct ExampleApp: SwiftUI.App {
    
    // register app delegate for Firebase setup
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate //<--- HERE
    
    @StateObject var appState = AppState()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(appState)
        }
    }
}
```

Inside this `AppDelegate` functions one obtains an FCM Token, with which the device is identified to subsequently send it notifications remotely. This token has to get sent to the server. This could be done inside the respective function inside the `AppDelegate` . However, there is a class `AppState` (ObservableObject protocol) that handles the user data and writing to the server, so it would make a lot more sense to write pass it to this class (or retrieve in the class from the `AppDelegate`?) and then push it from there.

How can this be accomplished?

edit: I guess this could be achieved by using a `static` property in the `AppDelegate` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65445473/9739903). Is using statics to access variables globally not bad practice? Is there a other (better) way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI app life cycle iOS14 where to put AppDelegate code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62538110/swiftui-app-life-cycle-ios14-where-to-put-appdelegate-code)

Comment: See linked solution. It also shows how to setup firebase without appdelegate

Comment: @flatasearth Please read the question again. The problem I have is a **result** of using exactly the same concept used in that link.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the "old way" of accessing the `delegate`

```
@MainActor //Required by the app delegate
class AppState: ObservableObject{
    lazy var appDelegate: AppDelegate? = {
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    }()
}
```

Then you can just use

```
appDelegate?.yourToken
```

`yourToken` referencing a property in the `delegate`